# XSD: Converting set of elements into array of complex types

Tags: xslt, xsd

Looking for someone to correct me.
I'm building transformation in custom system to finally get a JSON request [Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0#onlinemeetingpresenters-values)

Start XML:

```html
<participants>
  <attendees>
          <upn>testworkemail1@gmail.com</upn>
          <role>Presenter</role>
      </attendees>
      <attendees>
          <upn>testworkemail2@gmail.com</upn>
          <role>Presenter</role>
      </attendees>
</participants>
```

modifying XSD

```html
<xs:element name="participants">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="attendees">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="upn"/>
            <xs:element ref="role"/>
        </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

   <xs:element name="upn" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="role" type="xs:string"/>
```

this is the output in JSON, after processing

```html
"participants": {
        "attendees": {
            "upn": "testworkemail1@gmail.com",
            "role": "Presenter"
        },
        "attendees": {
            "upn": "testworkemail2@gmail.com",
            "role": "Presenter"
        }
    }
```

Although it's not accepted by MS Graph API as it's service expects in this format:

```html
"participants": {
        "attendees": [
            {
                "upn": "testworkemail1@gmail.com",
                "role": "presenter"
            },
            {
                "upn": "testworkemail2@gmail.com",
                "role": "presenter"
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I alter Either XML or XSD to get it to MS specification of JSON request with omitted attendee element names?

Comment: Frankly, I don't see why using the XSD schema of `xs:all` with a single `xs:element name="attendees"` would even allow two `attendees` elements in the XML instance, the schema allows for a single `attendees` element. And it is not clear at all which tool or which rules you use to convert the XML to JSON. But JSON doesn't allow any two properties of the same name at the same level, so, yes, your first example is not valid JSON.

Comment: There are many tools for converting XML to JSON and they all produce different results. You need to ask questions about a specific tool or library. Your particular tool is producing incorrect JSON, which is ... unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the 4th line of the XSD by specifying the upper bound limit to be unbounded has converted the array of attributes with out label.

```html
<xs:element name="attendees" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```